# How to add context name of application in Spring-cloud sidecar's configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I have one legacy non-Spring web application deployed on Tomcat. Its URL is `localhost:8080/myapp`.
There are four REST endpoints on this `myapp` which I can access as follows.

1. `localhost:8080/myapp/rest/users` [Http method is GET]
2. `localhost:8080/myapp/rest/user` [Http method is POST]
3. `localhost:8080/myapp/rest/user` [Http method is PUT]
4. `localhost:8080/myapp/rest/user` [Http method is Delete]

I created sidecar app on the same system. Its configuration is as follows

```
server:
  port: 19999

spring:
  application:
    name: sidecar
eureka:
  client:
    enabled: true
sidecar:
  port: 8080
```

Following is the configuration of ZUUL gateway application

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-api
server:
  port: 8764
zuul:
  routes:
    myapp:
      path: /myapp/**
      service-id: sidecar
      strip-prefix: false
    frontend:
      path: /**
      service-id: frontend
```

Sidecar and Gateway, both are connected to Eureka.
If I want to access myapp via Gateway, I have to use URL `localhost:8764/myapp/rest/users`.
My goal is to invoke rest endpoints like `localhost:8764/rest/users`
My question is how can mention context of legacy application(in this case, it is myapp) in sidecar application configuration ?

Comment: Short answer is a custom filter. I don't have time today for a long answer.

Comment: You mean, custom ZUUL filter in gateway ?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: That will not work in my case coz I am going to have multiple instances of service `sidecar` and it may have different contexts like `myapp` or `myapp_v1` or `myapp_v2`. So is there any way I can mention the 'context' of legacy app in the configuration of sidecar app ?

Comment: Not currently no.

Comment: @spencergibb I am thinking, in my case, it is ideal to put ZUUL filter in sidecar, is it  possible ? I tried to create filter and put it in sidecar but it is not getting executed. :(